# PowerCLI Get-VM output

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am working on a script, and I am having trouble with a section of code.  When I pass in a list of computers that are all found in VCenter, the script populates the $result object correctly with a list of servers and all of the information included.  If there are any errors (unable to find server in VCenter) the only thing that is returned is the error line (in the case of multiple errors, only the last error is in $result).  Any ideas what I can do to resolve this?

I know that it will work if I enclose the Get-VM statement in a foreach loop, but passing one server at a time to the VCenter takes a very long time.

```
try {
        $operation = Get-VM -Name $computers -ErrorAction Stop | Restart-VMGuest -Confirm:$false
        foreach ($comp in $operation) {
            $result += [pscustomobject] @{
                Server = $computer
                Status = $True
                Error = $False
                ErrorMessage = $null
                Stamp = Get-Date
                }
            }
        }
    catch {
        $result += [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $computer
            Status = $False
            Error = $True
            ErrorMessage = $_
            Stamp = Get-Date
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error is on the `Get-VM` operation, not a result in the collection, so you would only ever see one error.

Comment: OK.  So I would need to collect the results of the command, then process for errors?  I am not sure now I'd do that.

Comment: The only way is how you said, to put the `Get-VM` inside the foreach. You may also get somewhere by changing the `-ErrorAction` preference, but your catch block may never trigger so you'd have to find a different way of determining an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the try / catch is on the false position. Maybe if you put an if / else statement in the foreach this work?
 But I don't know how to check if `$comp` is en `error`...

```
 $operation = Get-VM -Name $computers -ErrorAction Stop | Restart-VMGuest -Confirm:$false

foreach ($comp in $operation) {
    If ($comp -eq "??error??") {
        $result += [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $computer
            Status = $True
            Error = $False
            ErrorMessage = $null
            Stamp = Get-Date
            }
    }
    Else {
        $result += [pscustomobject] @{
                Server = $computer
                Status = $False
                Error = $True
                ErrorMessage = $_
                Stamp = Get-Date
                }
            }
    }
```